# Компиляция приложений под .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Будет ли приложение написаное на С++ в Visual Studio под NET4 и скомпилированное на Windows 7 работать в Windows XP?

Comment: если будет установлен .NET Framework 4.0, то да!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В том случае, когда приложение включает только управляемый код, оно будет работать на Windows XP SP3 при условии, что на целевой машине установлен .NET Framework версии 4.0 и выше.

Comment: если [поиграться с реестром](http://otvet.mail.ru/question/22080560/), то и на SP2 будет работать

Comment: В настройках проекта приложения можно указать версию `.NET`. В `Windows 7` установлена `.NET 3.5`, на `XP` нужно самому устанавливать.